# Migrate firebase users to new project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to migrate a production flutter application with thousand of users to another firebase project, I success to migrate the firestore database but I struggle to find a way to migrate users from the authentication service.

I've exported all users from the old project to the new one by running these commands

```
firebase auth:export AllUsers.json --project my_old_project
firebase auth:import AllUsers.json --project my_new_project
```

but on the client side, I can't find a way to keep the same UID for users connected in anonymous mode. If I create an anonymous account on the old project, then migrate the application to the new firebase account, the UID is not saved and so a new account is created and the data are lost...

Is anyone know a solution to do that?

Comment: When a user signs in anonymously, Firebase generates a unique ID for that user. However, this ID is only generated for that specific project and cannot be transferred to another project.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I can't migrate users to another project? Really annoying since I want to create a new project to change the firestore location (which is not possible without re-creating another project)